# Google Play Services onRoomCreated error

Tags: android, multiplayer, google-play-services

i'm developing a multiplayer online game using Google Play Services and i have this problem.
SOMETIMES when i try to invite a player or to start a quick game, it returns error status 2, which is "STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED".

So i tried to reconnect the client using this method:

```
reconnectClients(BaseGameActivity.CLIENT_APPSTATE);
```

But it doesn't work.
I don't understand why sometimes it works and sometimes not..

Thank you!

Comment: Properly update the room time to time on every related callbacks.